# Reading a line from MULTI_SZ registry key in Wix

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am trying to read the local path of a share from registry and use it for my installation using Wix. I can find information about shares from this registry key SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares but the path is one of the values in this multi string key. Could you please let me know if this path information can be parsed from the key using Wix or better ways of getting this local path of a share in Wix than reading it from registry ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have any other option except for authoring a [RegistrySearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) element (specifying `raw` as a value of `Type` attribute) and parse it in a custom action.